# Docker compose vs Docker Run (Container Crashes on compose with same setup)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created a compose script, but the container kept exiting with code 0, i decided to turn the script into a docker run command, and the container created with the docker run command works just fine?

**Compose Script:**

```
version: "3"
services:
  debian-ssh:
    container_name: WebVestaCPDebian
    image: debian/bookworm-systemd:latest
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "1-65534:1-65534"
    networks:
      WebVestaCPDebian_NET:
        ipv4_address: x.x.x.x
    restart: always
    mac_address: "x:x:x:x:x"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '6'
          memory: 12G
    storage_opt:
      size: 100G
    volumes:
      - /data/WebVestaCPDebian/volume/home:/home
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw

networks:
  WebVestaCPDebian_NET:
    external: true
```

`with enviornment vars: (cgroupns=host)`

**docker run command:**

```
docker run --detach --name WebVestaCPDebian --mac-address "x:x:x:x:x" --net WebVestaCPDebian_NET --ip x.x.x.x --privileged -p 1-65534:1-65534 --cgroupns=host --volume=/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw --volume=/data/WebVestaCPDebian/volume/home:/home --memory 12G --cpus 6 debian/bookworm-systemd:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was building the compose script, i was using cgroupns and i kept getting the error "Additional property cgroupns is not allowed" but since the latest docker update, it has been added and named as cgroup in docker compose specs.

Since i was using it as an environment variable, the container created via compose script kept exiting.

Source: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8167#issuecomment-1571754909

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).